# Coq: how to apply one hypothesis to another

Tags: coq

Assume I have two hypotheses in the context, `a_b : A -> B` and `a : A`. I should be able to apply `a_b` to `a` to gain a further hypothesis, `b : B`.

That is, given the following state:

```
1 subgoal
A : Prop
B : Prop
C : Prop
a_b : A -> B
a : A
______________________________________(1/1)
C
```

There should be some tactic, `foo (a_b a)`, to transform this into the following state:

```
1 subgoal
A : Prop
B : Prop
C : Prop
a_b : A -> B
a : A
b : B
______________________________________(1/1)
C
```

But I don't know what `foo` is.

One thing I can do is this:

```
 assert B as b.
 apply a_b.
 exact a.
```

but this is rather long-winded, and scales badly if instead of `a_b a` I have some larger expression.

Another thing I can do is:

```
specialize (a_b a).
```

but this *replaces* the `a_b` hypothesis, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
pose proof (a_b a) as B.
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "apply a_b in a."

Comment: That would change the hyp. `a`, not give you a new one.