# In Coq, is there a way to get rid of "useless" preconditions in a hypothesis?

Tags: coq

Sometimes due to a combination of the `remember` and `induction` tactics, I end up with hypothesis that look like a bit like this:

```
Heqa: a = Foo b
IH1: a = Foo b -> bla_bla_bla
IH2: a = Foo b -> ble_ble_ble
```

Is there a quick way to get those useless `a = Foo b` preconditions in `IH1` and `IH2` out of the way? The only way to do that that I can think of is very verbose and repetitive:

```
assert (IH1': a = Foo b). { apply Heqa. }
apply IH1 in IH1'. clear IH1. rename IH1' into IH1.

assert (IH2': a = Foo b). { apply Heqa. }
apply IH2 in IH2'. clear IH2. rename IH2' into IH2.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `specialize` tactic:

```
specialize (IH1 Heqa).
specialize (IH2 Heqa).
```

will get you

```
Heqa: a = Foo b
IH1: bla_bla_bla
IH2: ble_ble_ble
```

which seems is what you want.

`specialize` applies some arguments to a hypothesis and rewrites it.

By the way, using a somewhat similar tactic `pose proof` we can keep the original hypothesis intact. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156622/coq-how-to-apply-one-hypothesis-to-another).